# Dynamic word wrapping in Kile stopped working in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: 21.10, kate, kile

Just noticed that dynamic word wrapping is not working in Kile 2.9.93 on Ubuntu 21.10.

The setting is in

Settings > Configure > Kile > Editor > Appearance > Dynamic Word Wrap

but no dynamic word wrapping is happening, regardless whether the checkbox is set or not.  The same thing in Kate works just fine.

Any hints highly appreciated because typing or editing long lines without dynamic word wrapping is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned that it is possible to activate dynamic word wrapping with the the word wrap option in the `View` menu.  This option changes dynamic wrapping for each tab independently and seems to override whatever is set in
`Settings > Configure > Kile > Editor > Appearance > Dynamic Word Wrap`.  Glad to be able to dynamically wrap again and I hope this helps someone.